# BaseEntity @Inheritance - how to inherit fields from superclass

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-couchbase

I'm trying to make a data model with `spring-data-couchbase`.

I created a super class called BaseEntity where the ID and basic fields for all SubClasses are declared. The `@IdSuffix` and `@IdPrefix` annotations are working fine for me, but the `@Field` annotation does not work.

I've tried `@Inheritance`, `@MappedSuperClass`, `@Document`, ...

Here is an example:

```java
@Data
@Document
public abstract class BaseEntity {

   @IdPrefix(order = 0) // works fine!
   @Field               //don't work
   protected long number;

   @IdSuffix(order =0) // works fine!
   private UUID uuid;

   public BaseEntity(long number){
      this.number = number;
      this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
   }
}

@Data
@Document
public class Entity extends BaseEntity{

   public Entity(long number){
      super(number);
   }

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationStrategy.USE_ATTRIBUTES, delimiter = "::")
    private String id;

   @Field                  // works!
   private LocalDate date;
}
```

The result is:

```
id= 1234567::467f970e-ab98-4244-afcf-7af81361d60a

{
   "date": 1435301400000
}
```

I'd expect the field number in the document.

Comment: Have you tryed `protected long number;` => `protected Long number;` ?

Comment: Yes. Still the same problem.

Comment: What's the framwork that bringed in `@IdPrefix` & `@IdSufix` ?

Comment: org.springframework.data.couchbase.core.mapping.id.IdPrefix

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem.

The `@IdPrefix` and the `@Field` Annotations don´t work together.

The solution:

```
@Data
@Document
public abstract class BaseEntity {

   @IdPrefix(order = 0) // works fine!
   protected long numberPrefix;

   @Field               // Solution
   protected long number;

   @IdSuffix(order =0) // works fine!
   private UUID uuid;

   public BaseEntity(long number){
      this.number = number;
      this.numberPrefix = number;
      this.uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
   }
}
```